# A task parameter as a drop down list

Tags: task, scom, management-pack

I am building a SCOM management package which adds a Task to some class.
I could have defined a list of Task Parameters, each consisting of and Name and a Value.

Is there any way I could set these Values to predefined Drop Down Lists to avoid typos?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. But you can restrict values via xsd schema.